# How to test async XMLHttpRequest callbacks in Jest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, testing, jestjs, xmlhttprequest

I have the following Jest test which includes calling a mock server using ajax with `XMLHttpRequest`:

```js
import mock from "xhr-mock";

describe("ajax callbacks", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    mock.setup();
  });

  afterAll(function() {
    mock.teardown();
  });

  it("gets called when done", function(done) {
    mock.get("/get-url", {
      status: 200,
      body: '{ "key": "value" }'
    });

    const doneCallback = jest.fn();

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "/get-url");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        doneCallback();
        done();
      }
    }
    xhr.send();

    expect(doneCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

which will obviously fail because the AJAX call is handled asynchronously and the expectation is made before the callback is called.

Is there any way where Jest can wait till the callback is called before making the expectation?

Please note that I cannot turn the request into a synchronous one because of the domain requirements. And neither can I turn it into a Promise based API just to be able to test it. This is just a simplified version of the test which is being written so that the folks here can grasp it easily. The actual code is different and it has abstractions to what is written here.

Comment: Why don't you put the expectation statement within `onreadystatechange` handler, before calling the `done()` function?

Comment: @slideshowp2 But it logically doesn't make sense. Cause if `onreadystatechange` handler does get run, then it automatically means that the `doneCallback` will run, so adding the expectations there would not have much value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by basically using the `async/await` support that Jest provides. The solution is to wrap the asynchronous request into a `Promise` and resolve the `Promise` when the `onreadystatechange` callback gets called. As such:

```js
import mock from "xhr-mock";

describe("ajax callbacks", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    mock.setup();
  });

  afterAll(function() {
    mock.teardown();
  });

  it("gets called when done", async function() {
    mock.get("/get-url", {
      status: 200,
      body: '{ "key": "value" }'
    });

    const doneCallback = jest.fn();

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "/get-url");

    await new Promise(function(resolve) {
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
          doneCallback();
          resolve();
        }
      }
      xhr.send();
    });

    expect(doneCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Using `await` will make the test pause till the `Promise` gets resolved. I know this feels a bit hacky. But that's all we have for now. I tried looking into other solutions but couldn't find any.

To know more about using `async/await` with Jest, refer [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous#asyncawait).

Comment: This works, but Jest provides a simpler way to promisification, the [`done` parameter](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous.html#callbacks), so you don't need to use `new Promise` or `async`/`await`.

Comment: @ggorlen I've given the reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64195652/how-to-test-async-xmlhttprequest-callbacks-in-jest#comment113538381_64195652).

Comment: I see, but the `doneCallback` feels redundant. I'm not sure what that accomplishes over calling `done` directly which implicitly asserts that the request succeeded. Are you trying to assert that the request didn't fail? If so, this seems like it'd timeout if it fails. I see you explain the actual code has other abstractions, but what's shown here seems like an antipattern in and of itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Sinon to mock XMLHttpRequests.

```
import { createFakeServer } from 'sinon';

describe('Example', () => {

    let xhr;

    beforeEach(() => xhr = createFakeServer());

    afterEach(() => xhr.restore());

    test('example calls callback', () => {
        jest.spyOn(exampleObject, 'exampleCallback');

        xhr.respondWith('POST', '/expected/url', [200, { }, JSON.stringify({ foo: 'response' })]);

        exampleObject.funcToDoRequest();

        xhr.respond();
    
        expect(exampleObject.exampleCallback).toBeCalledWith({ foo: 'response' });
    });

});
```

See more information from https://sinonjs.org/releases/v9.2.0/fake-xhr-and-server/

Another way would be to use setTimeout if xhr-mock is used. Wrap callback assertion to setTimeout and call done() callback for the Jest test. Feels kind of a hack, but works.

```
rest of your code
...

setTimeout(() => {
  expect(doneCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
  done();
});
```